# How to run a Nodejs block of code, periodically after each user signups

Tags: node.js, express

I have a site that lets users signups to. I want send each user a periodic mail, that occurs every 24hours after signup.
My problem is that this script has to run specific for every user...so let's say if user A signed up at 2pm, he gets a mail at exactly 2pm the next day, the day after, and so on, and if user B signs up at 2:01pm, he gets a mail too at exactly 2:01pm the next day, and so on.
I'm using Nodejs, how can I achieve this?

Comment: You can setup specific Cron jobs for each user once they sign up and inside the Cron job, use a mailer package like nodemailer to send emails.

Comment: Okay, what if I have lots of users? Won't it be tasking to the server? I mean setting up from jobs for each user??

Comment: Yes it will be if there are many users. In that, you can try the following: Save the email ID and the time for the notification in a database. Then run a background script periodically (using Cron) to check the database and get the entries that are nearer to the time of script execution; nearer can be say 15 minutes after the scheduled entry or before it for example. The catch is it might not be exactly at the time you want but will be accurate to a couple minutes to an hour (depending on the frequency of cron script).

Comment: Okay, thanks a lot...I think I'll run it every 10mins